# Access control from Form in Class

Tags: c#

I'm new in objective programing, just started learning so probably my question will be stupid for most of you but, I really don't know how to achieve what i need.

I have Form1 with control - `combobox_kraje`, user choose country and `click button`, here is the button code

[image]

Here `Messagebox.Show(combobox_kraje.text)` show me correct value of this control.

Now i want to access combobox_kraje in my class

[image]

Here `Messagebox.Show(form.combobox_kraje.text)` show me incorrect value (empty MessageBox).

Can you please explain me how i can access that form control in my class?

Comment: add constructor like `Public MyClass(Form1 f1){this.f1 = f1;}`, then you can use f1, also remember change combobox's modifiers to public.

Comment: What is `form` ? how do you initialize/assign it?

Comment: @LeiYang combobox is already set as public

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Form1 form = new Form1();

Comment: And how do you show the form? from the same instance? probably not

Comment: @JustSomeNewbie, so add constructor of your class like i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting something to public to be able to access it outside isn´t allways a good idea and at least here there´s a better approach to do this. Just add a property to your form that returns the combonboxes text-value:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public string TheMessageText { return this.combobox_kraje.Text; }
}
```

Now access it via `form.TheMessageText`. This way you can leave the actual control `private` and only provide those parts to the outside that are relevant, not the entire control.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `form` (which is initialized by `new Form1()`), but it is not the instance that is shown.

You should pass the instance that is shown to the class and assign it to `form` instead:

```
public MyClass(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form = form1;
}
```

Also as @HimBromBeere stated, you should add a property to expose the text it self, instead of using a public control.